# Run the same Python script in multiple differnet shells with different arguments?

Tags: python, flask

I want to build a website using Flask that will allow users to control a Python bot that I recently created, for example I will want it to when you press a 'Turn on' button from the website it will create a new shell that will start running this bot, but there needs to be a different shell running for every user that turns the bot on, as there will be specific arguments (API keys) that the user will need to provide the bot.

How is this achievable in terms of running the same Python script multiple times from the website for different users and different arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen` to open shell and close it whenever you want

```py
import subprocess

class bot_process:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "bot.py", *args])
    def stop(self):
        self.process.terminate()
```

Comment: You probably want `Popen(["python", "bot.py", *args])` instead

Comment: @mousetail I think you're right. All the examples in documentation use `list` instead of `string` as input  but both of them work the same way. What is the difference between them exactly?

Comment: List only works if you need only one argument or set `shell=True` which creates a lot of security issues. You want list nearly always